# How to avoid using a global variable as a parameter to a decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am writing a python script where I am using a decorator(retry is the one I am using) that takes a parameter (tries).  I want the parameter to be configurable from a command line argument.  The only way I can figure out how to set the parameter for the decorator is by reading my arguments into a global variable. I hate this from a design perspective.  It makes writing unit tests and anything else that wants to import any functions from my script reliant on the command line arguments being all the same.

Here is a dumbed down example of the problem I am having:

```
import argparse
from functools import wraps

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--test_value', dest='test_value', required=True, default="sample value")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
args = get_args()

def decorator_example(test_value):
    def deco_example(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def f_example(*args, **kwargs):
            print "The value I need is", test_value
            return f(*args, **kwargs) 
        return f_example 
    return deco_example

@decorator_example(args.test_value)
def test():
    print "running test"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

If anyone can think of a better way to do this without having args be a global, please share! I have  exhausted the internet searching for a better way... I want to call `getargs()` in main and pass the arguments around as needed....

Comment: It's more than a little confusing to have parameters, local variables, and global variables all named `args` that sometimes mean the args to a function and sometimes the `argparse` args to the program…

Comment: Anyway, `args` obviously has to be accessible to wherever you're using it. If you're using it in a decorator for a global function (as you are), it has to be a global. In the same way that `test` has to be a global if you want to call it from the top level. How else could it possibly work?

Comment: What about doing `get_args().test_value` in the body of `f_example`?

Comment: @abarnet: Yes args is not the best name; neither is test.  It was just quick example code. My program is longer and more complex.

Comment: @abarnert That is similar to what jpmc26's second suggestion is.. I am going to try something like that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a decorator is appropriate here. A class seems more suitable precisely because of the problem you're facing. Something like this:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, test_value):
        self.test_value = test_value

    def test(self):
        print "The value I need is", self.test_value
        self._inner_test()

    def _inner_test():
        print "running test"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = get_args()
    t = TestClass(args.test_value)
    t.test()
```

How exactly to structure the class is not clear from the example you have given and would depend on what you're actually doing, but I think something in this vein will provide you with a more robust solution than trying to shoehorn this into decorators.

Classes are designed to maintain state and provide modified behavior based on that state. That is what you're doing. Your application has state that modifies its behavior. Decorators are designed to wrap extra, static functionality around an existing method.

However, if that is unsuitable, another alternative is to simply allow your arguments to be global. Something along the lines of this:

config.py

```
import argparse

test_value = None

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--test_value', dest='test_value', required=True, default="sample value")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

def configure():
    global test_value
    args = parse_args()
    test_value = args.test_value
```

main.py

```
from functools import wraps
import config

def decorator_example(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def f_example(*args, **kwargs):
        print "The value I need is", config.test_value
        return f(*args, **kwargs) 
    return f_example

@decorator_example
def test():
    print "running test"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    config.configure()
    test()
```

One nice side of this solution is that it gives you an obvious way to also supplement  your arguments with a configuration file. Note that this should actually work since `config.test_value` is not actually read until `test` is called.

Comment: I am trying to do exponential backoff with the retry decorator; I just want the number of trys to be configurable.  I need to use the decorator in many classes, so the class solution doesn't make sense.   The other solution you offer sounds like it may help... I will consider it.  Thanks!

Comment: @robinlmorris 5 years too late, I know, but it occurs to me that the class would work fine if the class accepts another function to call as an initializer parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Separate those things which are useful upon import from those things which are only relevant when run as a script:

```
from functools import wraps

def decorator_example(test_value):
    def deco_example(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def f_example(*args, **kwargs):
            print "The value I need is", test_value
            return f(*args, **kwargs) 
        return f_example 
    return deco_example

def base_test():
    print "running test"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    def get_args():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('-t', '--test_value', dest='test_value',
                            required=True, default="sample value")
        args = parser.parse_args()
        return args

    args = get_args()
    test = decorator_example(args.test_value)(base_test)
    test()
```

I think the issue of global variables is a red-herring here. There is nothing wrong with *constant* global variables. Every time you import a module, the module name is a global variable. Every time you define a function (at the module level), the function name becomes a global variable.

Problems arise only when functions *modify* global variables. When that happens, understanding the behavior of functions that depend on the global can become much more complex. If a chain of functions each modify the same global, then you can no longer understand each function as an isolated unit. You have to grok all the functions and how they interact with that global at the same time. This can get complicated quickly and it is why this path often leads to spaghetti code.

This is why *modifying* global variables should be avoided. But you aren't modifying any global variables here, so I think this is a non-issue. My beef with `args.test_value` is not that it is global, but rather that there was not sufficient separation of module code versus script code. `args.test_value` belongs with the script code.

Comment: Manually applying the decorator causes parts of my code to be knowledgeable about the decorator (which I do not want). I see your point...  I should move the "script" specific part of code into another file.  However, if my decorator needs a global argument it has to import some of the code from the script file into the module file which is the wrong direction to import... I am fine with globals when they are constant, but not when I may want to override them for testing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Parse your args in the "if **name**" section and pass them to your function as an arg.  That way other scripts can specify a value for args instead of relying on command line arguments.

Comment: That is what I would like to do, but it doesn't fix the problem I am encountering with the decorator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your can't define the decorator until after the function you want to apply it to is defined. One workaround would be to postpone decorating the functions until the value is defined, which in turns requires that they be stored somewhere until that happens.
It also means a global variable will be *required* temporarily and its use isolated from the rest of the program. Here's how that could be done with your sample code:

```
from functools import wraps

class decorator_example(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        global _funcs
        self.f = f
        try:
            _funcs.append(self)  # remember decorator_example instances
        except NameError:
            _funcs = [self]  # first one

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'running decoratored {}() function'.format(self.f.__name__)
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)

def apply_decorator(deco, test_value):
    global _funcs
    for d in _funcs:
        print 'decorating function {}()'.format(d.f.__name__)
        d.f = deco(d.f, test_value)
    del _funcs  # no longer needed

@decorator_example
def test():
    print "running test"

def deco_example(f, test_value):
    @wraps(f)
    def f_example(*args, **kwargs):
        print "The value I need is", test_value
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return f_example

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    def get_args():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('-t', '--test_value', dest='test_value',
                            required=True, default="sample value")
        args = parser.parse_args()
        return args

    args = get_args()
    apply_decorator(deco_example, args.test_value)
    test()
```

Comment: Manually applying the decorator causes parts of my code to be knowledgeable about the decorator (which I do not want).  Thanks though.

Answer (score -3):

If I understand it correctly, usage of global variables can be alleviated with class and member variables. But in Python unless you design carefully, you can not avoid global variables